# search a keyword from the result of the subquery with multiple rows results

Tags: mysql

I would like to search a keyword from the result of the subquery. In my subquery I already filtered the grants I need from different category required. Now I need to search the keyword in title for those results.  Or is there efficient way to do this query because my work is not working after days stuck?

I tried working on the IN but still did not get it right.

```
SELECT DISTINCT gt.grant_id, gt.*,
infra.infra_name,
infrasub.infrasub_name,
lga.lga_name,
stream.stream_id,
stream.stream_n,
stream.stream_dept,
stream.stream_desc
FROM
grant_tbl AS gt
LEFT JOIN grant_details AS gd
ON (
gt.grant_id = gd.grant_id
)
LEFT JOIN infra_sub_tbl AS infrasub
ON (
infrasub.infra_sub_id = gd.infrasub_id
)
LEFT JOIN infra_tbl AS infra
ON (
infra.infra_id = gd.infra_id
)
LEFT JOIN lga_tbl AS lga
ON (
  lga.lga_id = gd.lga_id
)
LEFT JOIN streams_tbl AS stream
ON (
stream.stream_id = gd.stream_id
)
WHERE gt.grant_id  IN 
(
SELECT DISTINCT gd.grant_id, CONCAT(gt.grant_name,"|",gt.grant_desc,"|",gt.keywords)
FROM grant_details AS gd
LEFT JOIN grant_tbl AS gt
ON gt.grant_id = gd.grant_id
WHERE gd.lga_id = 1
OR gd.lga_id = 2
AND gd.stream_id = 1
OR gd.stream_id = 2
GROUP BY gt.grant_id
)
```

my result should narrow down from my subquery. display only with matching keyworkds

Comment: Hi perhaps inspect the output of the subquery to make sure it matches?

Answer (score 0):

You can use EXISTS instead of IN,

```
SELECT DISTINCT gt.grant_id, gt.*,
infra.infra_name,
infrasub.infrasub_name,
lga.lga_name,
stream.stream_id,
stream.stream_n,
stream.stream_dept,
stream.stream_desc
FROM grant_tbl AS gt
LEFT JOIN grant_details AS gd ON gt.grant_id = gd.grant_id
LEFT JOIN infrasub_tbl AS infrasub ON infrasub.infrasub_id = gd.infrasub_id
LEFT JOIN infra_tbl AS infra ON infra.infra_id = gd.infra_id
LEFT JOIN lga_tbl AS lga ON lga.lga_id = gd.lga_id
LEFT JOIN stream_tbl AS stream ON stream.stream_id = gd.stream_id
WHERE exists
(
SELECT DISTINCT gd.grant_id,CONCAT(gt2.grant_name,"|",gt2.grant_desc,"|",gt2.keywords)
FROM grant_details AS gd
LEFT JOIN grant_tbl AS gt2 ON gt2.grant_id = gd.grant_id
WHERE (gd.lga_id = 10 OR gd.lga_id = 20) AND (gd.stream_id = 100 OR gd.stream_id = 200)
and gt.grant_id=gt2.grant_id
GROUP BY gt.grant_id
)
```

Hope this helps.